# web.py downloading images

Tags: python, http, web.py

I'm fairly new to web applications and I'm trying to write a web.py server that will allow me to download an image. As of right now I'm keeping it down to the bare minimum until I can see how it all works. I have this bit of code that will return me an image when I go the correct URL:

```
class download:

   def GET(self, args):
       path = 'path/to/image' 
       web.header('Content-type','images/jpeg')
       web.header('Content-transfer-encoding','binary') 
       return open(path, 'rb').read()
```

So when I go to the URL it automatically downloads the image however, it names it as 'download' and has no extension. Is there a way to specify the file name for when it get's downloaded? Does this have to be specified in the headers somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need set the `Content-Disposition` header, for example:

```
web.header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="fname.ext"')
```

reference: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.5.1

Answer (score 2):

You want the `content-disposition` header:

```
'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=my_filename.jpg'
```

Comment: Adding the line: web.header('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=file.jpg') worked. Thanks!

Comment: The `filename=my_filename.jpg` specific to the new name of the downloaded file